# fix crm cluster in sles12sp5 for 12 node master slave configuration

Tags: cluster, crm, slave

When we try to add the additional servers 0f 6 004,005,006,104,105 & 106.to the existing server of primary 001, 002 & 003 Secondary 101,102 & 103.

crm configure show

node 1: pbh001 
attributes hana_pbh_site=PBH001 
attributes hana_pbh_gra=2.0 hana_pbh_srmode=syncmem
node 10: pbh106 
attributes hana_pbh_site=PBH101 
attributes hana_pbh_gra=2.0 hana_pbh_srmode=syncmem 
attributes hana_pbh_vhost=pbh104 hana_pbh_remoteHost=pbh003
node 11: pbh004 
attributes hana_pbh_site=PBH001 hana_pbh_vhost=pbh004 hana_pbh_remoteHost=pbh103 
attributes hana_pbh_gra=2.0 hana_pbh_srmode=syncmem
node 12: pbh005 
attributes hana_pbh_site=PBH101 
attributes hana_pbh_gra=2.0 hana_pbh_srmode=syncmem
node 13: pbh006 
attributes hana_pbh_srmode=syncmem
node 2: pbh002 
attributes hana_pbh_site=PBH001 
attributes hana_pbh_gra=2.0 hana_pbh_srmode=syncmem
node 3: pbh003 
attributes hana_pbh_site=PBH001 
attributes hana_pbh_gra=2.0 hana_pbh_srmode=syncmem
node 4: ppdblppbh101 
attributes hana_pbh_site=PBH101 
attributes hana_pbh_gra=2.0 hana_pbh_srmode=syncmem hana_pbh_vhost=pbh101 hana_pbh_remoteHost=pbh103
node 5: pbh102 
attributes hana_pbh_site=PBH101 
attributes hana_pbh_gra=2.0 hana_pbh_srmode=syncmem
node 6: pbh104 
attributes hana_pbh_site=PBH101 hana_pbh_remoteHost=mpbh100 hana_pbh_vhost=pbh104 
attributes hana_pbh_srmode=syncmem
node 7: mpbh100 
attributes hana_pbh_site=PBH101 
attributes hana_pbh_gra=2.0 hana_pbh_srmode=syncmem
node 8: pbh103 
attributes hana_pbh_site=PBH101 
attributes hana_pbh_gra=2.0 hana_pbh_srmode=syncmem
node 9: pbh105 
attributes hana_pbh_site=PBH101 
attributes hana_pbh_gra=2.0 hana_pbh_srmode=syncmem
primitive rsc_SAPHanaCon_PBH_HDB00 ocf:suse:SAPHanaController 
op start interval=0 timeout=3600 
op stop interval=0 timeout=3600 
op promote interval=0 timeout=3600 
op monitor interval=60 role=Master timeout=700 
op monitor interval=61 role=Slave timeout=700 
params SID=PBH InstanceNumber=00 PREFER_SITE_TAKEOVER=true DUPLICATE_PRIMARY_TIMEOUT=7200 AUTOMATED_REGISTER=false
primitive rsc_SAPHanaTop_PBH_HDB00 ocf:suse:SAPHanaTopology 
op monitor interval=10 timeout=600 
op start interval=0 timeout=600 
op stop interval=0 timeout=300 
params SID=PBH InstanceNumber=00
primitive rsc_ip_PBH_HDB00 IPaddr2 
op monitor interval=10s on-fail=restart timeout=20s 
params ip=xx.xx.xx.xxx 
meta target-role=Started
primitive stonith-sbd stonith:external/sbd 
params pcmk_action_limit=-1 pcmk_delay_max=30s 
meta target-role=Started
ms msl_SAPHanaCon_PBH_HDB00 rsc_SAPHanaCon_PBH_HDB00 
meta clone-node-max=1 master-max=1 interleave=true target-role=Started
clone cln_SAPHanaTop_PBH_HDB00 rsc_SAPHanaTop_PBH_HDB00 
meta clone-node-max=1 interleave=true target-role=Started
location SAPHanaCon_not_on_majority_maker msl_SAPHanaCon_PBH_HDB00 -inf: mpbh100
location SAPHanaTop_not_on_majority_maker cln_SAPHanaTop_PBH_HDB00 -inf: mpbh100
location cli-prefer-rsc_ip_PBH_HDB00 rsc_ip_PBH_HDB00 role=Started inf: pbh001
colocation col_saphana_ip_PBH_HDB00 2000: rsc_ip_PBH_HDB00:Started msl_SAPHanaCon_PBH_HDB00:Master
location loc_ip_not_on_majority_maker rsc_ip_PBH_HDB00 -inf: mpbh100
order ord_SAPHana_PBH_HDB00 1000: cln_SAPHanaTop_PBH_HDB00 msl_SAPHanaCon_PBH_HDB00
property SAPHanaSR: 
hana_pbh_site_lss_PBH101=1 
hana_pbh_site_srr_PBH101=S 
hana_pbh_glob_srmode=syncmem 
hana_pbh_site_lss_PBH001=1 
hana_pbh_site_srr_PBH001=P 
hana_pbh_site_mns_PBH001=pbh001 
hana_pbh_site_mns_PBH101=pbh101 
hana_pbh_site_lpt_PBH101=10 
hana_pbh_site_lpt_PBH001=1676773312 
hana_pbh_glob_sync_state=SFAIL 
hana_pbh_glob_sec=- 
hana_pbh_glob_srHook=SOK 
hana_pbh_glob_prim=PBH001 
hana_pbh_glob_upd=ok
property cib-bootstrap-options: 
have-watchdog=true 
dc-version="1.1.24+20210811.f5abda0ee-3.30.3-1.1.24+20210811.f5abda0ee" 
cluster-infrastructure=corosync 
cluster-name=pbhcluster 
no-quorum-policy=freeze 
stonith-enabled=true 
concurrent-fencing=true 
stonith-action=reboot 
stonith-timeout=259 
maintenance-mode=false 
last-lrm-refresh=1681574487 
configure 
property 
maintenance-mode=false
rsc_defaults rsc-options: 
resource-stickiness=1000 
migration-threshold=5
op_defaults op-options: 
timeout=600

Due to some TLS error when we have executed on pbh001 csync2 -xv

```
          [ 4 root ] $ csync2 -xv
          Connecting to host pbh006 (SSL) ...
          Connect to xx.xx.xxx.xx:30865 (pbh006).
          The hash size used in signature (32) is less than the expected (48)
          Updating /etc/corosync/corosync.conf on ppdblppbh006 ...
          File stays in dirty state. Try again later...
          Connecting to host pbh005 (SSL) ...
          Connect to xx.xx.xx.xx:30865 (pbh005).
          The hash size used in signature (32) is less than the expected (48)
          Config command failed.
          ERROR: Connection to remote host `pbh005' failed.
          Host stays in dirty state. Try again later...
          Connecting to host pbh004 (SSL) ...
          Connect to xx.xx.xxx.xxx:30865 (pbh004).
          SSL: handshake failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated. (GNUTLS_E_PREMATURE_TERMINATION)
```

Due to which we tried removing pbh004 & then re-add the cluster, that made the cluster out of sync between the clusters.
Please do suggest on how to get rid of situation..